# How is $ B_n = 1- \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} \frac{B_k}{n-k+1} $ Where $B_n$ are the Bernoulli Numbers with $B_1 = \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, summation, analytic-number-theory, bernoulli-numbers

So I was browing Wikipedia just looking at Bernoulli Number identities and I stumbled across this
$$ B_m^+ = 1- \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{m}{k} \frac{B_k^+}{m-k+1} $$
The Wikipedia page said that this identity was derived from the identity :
$$ 
\sum_{k=0}^{m}\left(\begin{array}{c}
m+1 \\
k
\end{array}\right) B_{k}^{+}=m+1
$$
My question is, how are these identities derived? Wikipedia gives the reference for these theorems to be from the page on Bernoulli Numbers on WolframMathWorld but I can't find the proof of any of these identities there. Can anyone guide me to or state a proof of either identity? (From the definition of Bernoulli Numbers stated below)
$$ 
\frac{t}{1-e^{-t}}=\frac{t}{2}\left(\operatorname{coth} \frac{t}{2}+1\right) \quad=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{B_{m}^{+} t^{m}}{m !}
$$

Comment: Bernoulli numbers are defined as the coefficients in the power series expansion of $b(z)=\frac{z}{e^z-1}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{B_n}{n!}z^n$ around $z=0$ (Notice that $z=0$ is a removable singularity. Form there, you may obtained some of the identities you quoted.

Comment: "From the definition of Bernoulli Numbers"? Quote that definition, please! There are at least two, and (sorry!) I'd like to know if you know at least one of them, before writing anything up.

Comment: Professor Vector's comment is extremely well taken.  Your query is **absolutely meaningless** unless and until you edit your query to provide *some* definition of Bernoulli numbers.  You can't expect mathSE reviewers to *reason in a vacuum*.

Comment: @ProfessorVector You're right I should've stated a defintion, I've edited my question to include a definition for $B^{+}_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Wikipedia says, the first identity can be obtained from the second by "solving" the latter for $\ B_m^+\ $:
\begin{align}
m+1&=\sum_{k=0}^m{m+1\choose k}B_k^+\\
&=(m+1)B_m^++\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{(m+1)!}{k!\,(m+1-k)!}B_k^+\\
&=(m+1)\left(B_m^++\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{m!}{k!\,(m-k)!}\left(\frac{B_k^+}{m-k+1}\right)\right)\\
&=(m+1)\left(B_m^++\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}{m\choose k}\frac{B_k^+}{m-k+1}\right)\ .
\end{align}
Dividing through by $\ m+1\ $ and subtracting $\ \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}{m\choose k}\frac{B_k^+}{m-k+1}\ $ from both sides of this equation gives the required first identity.

Here is a version of [reuns's derivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3919862/how-is-b-n-1-sum-k-0n-1-binomnk-fracb-kn-k1-where-b-n/3920210#3920210) of the second identity which works directly from the identity
$$
\frac{t}{1-e^{-t}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{B_k^+t^k}{k!}\ .
$$
Multiplying both sides of this identity by $\ e^t-1\ $ gives
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{t^{m+1}}{m!}&=
te^t\\
&=\big(e^t-1\big)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{B_k^+t^k}{k!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{B_k^+t^{n+k+1}}{(n+1)!k!}\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty t^{m+1}\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{B_k^+}{(m+1-k)!k!}\ .
\end{align}
Equating coefficients of $\ t^{m+1}\ $ gives
$$
\frac{1}{m!}=\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{B_k^+}{(m+1-k)!k!}\ ,
$$
and multiplying this equation by $\ (m+1)!\ $ gives the required identity.

Comment: and how to do I obtain the first equality?

Comment: See [reuns's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3919862/how-is-b-n-1-sum-k-0n-1-binomnk-fracb-kn-k1-where-b-n/3920210#3920210).

Answer (score 0):

The definition of $B_k$ is $$\frac{z}{e^z-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k!} z^k$$
it gives
$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{z^{m+1}}{m!}=(e^z-1)\frac{-z}{e^{-z}-1}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty z^{m+1} \sum_{k=0}^m\frac{(-1)^k B_k}{k! (m-k+1)!} $$

Conclude by equating the coefficients and using $B_k^+ = (-1)^k B_k$.